# Deserialize a Object with json returns an InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, json.net

I have an Class with an object property set to antoher Class.
When I serialize it, everything seems fine and the json looking good.
But when I want to try to deserialize the string again it gives an error.

[Example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uBo7Iv)

Comment: Use this tool https://json2csharp.com/ its easy to get the struct of your c# class if you know the json format.

Comment: Its runtime?!...

Comment: You have an `object Value` property. All type info is lost when serializing. Why do you expect C# to be able to cast an arbitrary object to a class?

Comment: Because I tell him how to do it with the cast?!

Comment: You can't cast an Apple to a Car, that's basic OO which C# enforces. Explain your problem properly, and include the code in your question. Now in comments to the answer you are explaining more of your use case; all of that info should be in your question. Please [edit] it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your exception:
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'SimpleClass'.
at Program.Main()

```
(SimpleClass)item.Value
```

Here you trying cast `object` to `SimpleClass` and its not possible. Serialiser deserialised json into type `object` and instance have type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`. You should change type of `ArgumentBaseV2.Value` to SimpleClass

```
class ArgumentBaseV2 
{
    ...
    public SimpleClass Value {get; set;}
}
```

Or you can use [generic type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters):

```
class ArgumentBaseV2<T>
{
    ...
    public T Value {get; set;}
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var myClass = new ArgumentBaseV2<SimpleClass>();
...
var deserialised = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ArgumentBaseV2<SimpleClass>>(json);
```

Comment: Yeah, can't do that... the object could be any class, its dynamic in my code, its just an example

Comment: You can define it as a Type https://dotnetfiddle.net/qn2w27